# Deja Dup stopped making scheduled backups

Tags: backup

I don't remember to have done anything but it stopped working. It doesn't do any scheduled backups anymore. It works perfectly if I manually do the backups but the scheduled backups do not work anymore. Any idea what to check? What to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently after a reboot it works again....anyways.